# Probability of a deck of cards

Tags: probability

Suppose you have a deck of 52 cards with 13 cards in each of the 4 suits. What is the probability of drawing 2 cards and getting a pair if you replace the first card and shuffle before drawing the second card?

Comment: Is drawing the same card twice a pair?

Comment: What does it mean to get "a pair" ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are three possible interpretations of "pair" in this context, which you need to clarify in your post. The first is "same card", the second is "same face value", the third is "same suit". Given that the definition of "pair" in card games is usually "same face value", that's the interpretation I'll be going with (unless otherwise stated by you).

The probability of drawing any card is $1$, obviously. If the card is replaced and the deck shuffled before drawing again, there will be $4$ out of $52$ with the same face value as the one you drew first. The probability of getting a pair is then $1\times\frac{4}{52}=\frac{1}{13}$.